# Would it be a bad idea to use Firebase UID as the datastore key name for users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-datastore

I assume since it's not monotonic, it would create a well distributed key space, and doing so would provide instant lookups.  One downside I can think of is locking myself into firebase auth.  Is there a better strategy?  Often I need to update a user record atomically, especially if it doesn't exist yet, and since transactions only allow ancestor queries (I have not been updated to the new firestore datastore mode as far as I know), I can't very well search and update atomically.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to go?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Just that I'm using the go datastore API -- but you're right that it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common to use Firebase Authentication's UID as the key for a document for that user, both in Datastore and in Firestore.

So: no, it won't be a bad idea per se. It of course always depends on your exact use-case and implementation though, so post back with a more concrete question if you run into problems.