# Firebase Authentication and datastore mode within a single project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-datastore

My app is using [Google Sign-in Javascript Library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in). I have to migrate to another logic because this library is discontinued. I am considering to migrate to [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

My app is already using firestore in datastore mode.
I know both [firestore native mode and datastore mode can not be used within a single project](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore).
But I am not sure this is the same for Firebase Authentication and Firestore in datastore mode.

Can I use both Firebase Authentication and Firestore in datastore mode within a single project?

Comment: You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918874/16531380) and see if this answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to be using Firestore to use Firebase Authentication.  So, you can use Firestore in Datastore mode & Firebase Authentication in the same project.